# On which node does shuffling and sorting occur-on the nodes with mapper tasks OR on the node with reducer task/s?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

My query is whether shuffling and sorting happen for each mapper task output(not combining) OR does it occur after merging all mapper task outputs on the node with the reducer.What exactly is shuffling.I have seen different definiitons for it.On some videos and even in the book The Definite Guide,shuffling means combining pairs with the same key value.But on some blogs, it is the process of transferring mapper o/p s to reducer.Which of them is correct?

Comment: check this link: [Shuffle and sort for mapreduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562643/shuffle-and-sort-for-mapreduce/39566051#39566051)