# How Hadoop distribute data and mapreduce task across multiple data nodes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

i am new to hadoop and i read many pages of hadoop mapreduce and hdfs but still not able to clear one concept.

May be this question is foolish or unusal,if it is so than so sorry for that.
My question is, suppose i had created a word count program for a file of size 1 GB in hadoop in which the map function will take each line as a input and output  as a key-value pair and reduce function will take input 
as key-value pair and simply iterate list and count total number of times a word came in that file.

Now my question is since this file is stored in chunks across multiple data nodes and the map-reduce execute on each data-node parallely. Say my file is stored on two datanode and file on first data-node contains word "hadoop" 5 times and file on second data-node contains word "hadoop" 7 times.So basically 
output of whole map reduce process will be:

hadoop:7

hadoop:5

as 2 map-reduce functions are executed on 2 different data-nodes parallely,
But output should be sum of count of "hadoop" word on both file and that is :
hadoop:13

So how would i achieve this or am i missing some concept here.Please help i am badly stuck with this concept and i am so sorry if i am unable to make you understand what i want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have *read many pages of Hadoop Mapreduce and HDFS* but you seemed to have missed the ones containing the stage after Map and before Reduce, which is called Shuffle and Sort.

Basically what it does is, it shuffles the data from all mappers and sends the lines with same keys to the same reducer in a sorted order. So, in your case, both `hadoop 7` and `hadoop 5` will go the same reducer which will reduce it to `hadoop 12` (Not 13!)

You can get more information about Shuffle and Sort easily on the web. There are [questions like this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562643/shuffle-and-sort-for-mapreduce) which you can read.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for your post.Now my concept is cleared.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are completly missing the concept of the reducer because thats exactly its function ,the reducer input will be a key(in this case hadoop) and a list of values associated with this key(7 and 5) , so your reducer program will iterate the values list and do the summation and then hadoop,13.